# The arcsine is "not really a function"

Tags: functions, trigonometry

My math teacher said that later on in life, if you pursue math, you would see that the arcsine function isn't actually a function. I do not see how it's not a function.

Comment: Did your teacher actually mean the _arcsine_ function?

Comment: Ask your teacher to elaborate.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel  no I'm pretty sure he didn't mean arcsine. he said sine.

Comment: @quasi i tried but ill do it again. do i assume it's a function for now. like it's really a function right?

Comment: If we use "a binary relation between two sets that associates every element of the first set to exactly one element of the second set" as a definition of a function, the sine is most definitely a function. Perhaps the teacher was slightly wrong - actually I think my teacher said the same to me when I was a teenager, and I was also thinking about this. Nowadays, I just think that they were wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's a function. Teschers can sometimes have misconceptions.

Comment: I have bookmarked this question because, even though sine is *most definitely* a function that maps $\mathbb R\to[-1,1]$ (or $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$), I am still very curious what the teacher meant. If/when you ask them, and if/when they provide at least a hint to what else they thought the sine *might* be, do let us know, and then we can explain it in more detail.

Comment: @parcly taxel  yep he really meant the arcsine function that it's not really an inverse function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following clarification from the OP that the arcsine function had been referred to: the arcsine is "not really a function" because there are infinitely many solutions to (for example) $\sin x=0$, so $\arcsin0$ could be any one of infinitely many values, whereas a function must map one input to one output. $\arcsin$ is therefore, *stricto sensu*, a *multifunction*.

Implementations of the arcsine in programming languages must choose one *principal value* out of infinitely many to serve as the aforementioned $x$, which leads to *branch cuts* over which that principal value is not continuous. For the arcsine's case, those branch cuts most often are $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is $\sin$ a perfectly well-defined function in the set-theoretic sense, we actually have an effective formula to compute the values of this function. Taking a wild guess here on what the teacher might have meant, perhaps it would be that relying on the geometric meaning of the sine function is not a terribly accurate way of doing things. That would be a correct statement. There is a very rigorous way to define the sine function but it relies on a pretty heavy theorem.

Here we go: The sine function is the unique function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying the initial condition $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$ and the differential equation $f''=-f$. In order for this to be a legitimate definition we invoke a theorem from the theory of function that guarantees that this particular differential equation does have a unique solution given the initial condition.

So, the sine function exists as a particular case of a theorem that allows us to construct many other functions. Now, from this information about the sine function one can find its Taylor series, compute its radius of convergence to be $\infty$, and use the remainder form in order to compute $\sin(t)$ for any value of $t\in \mathbb R$ and to any degree of accuracy (given sufficient computational time).

I would not say that the existence of the sine function is trivial. But it certainly is a function. Perhaps it is worth noting here that the common definition of $\sin(t)$ as the $Y$ coordinate of the point on the unit circle at $t$ radians from the positive $X$ axis measuring counterclockwise is correct but it relies on the notion of distance/angle. That is a tricky business. These geometric subtleties are avoided by the theorem mentioned above, essentially converting the whole thing to a more algebraic situation and good dose of analysis.

Comment: Some authors (e.g. Spivak) avoid the problem of defining sine using arc lengths by defining it in terms of *area*. This means that the geometric interpretation of sine is mostly preserved, and it can then be shown that sine satisfies the differential equations you mentioned above.

Comment: $c\sin x$ meets your definition for every $c$. You should also say $f^\prime(0)=1$.

Comment: @J.G. absolutely. Many thanks!

Comment: @Joe Thanks for adding a reference to that fact.

Comment: You've typed $f(0)=f^\prime(0)=0$ instead of $f(0)=0,\,f^\prime(0)=1$.

Comment: Thanks again @J.G.

Comment: I've got clarification that the arcsine was meant, not sine. Your answer is no longer on point.